# GAE Search: Relationships between documents in index

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search, app-engine-ndb, google-search-api

I'd like to return a result object which contains the indexed document AND other information, from another entity, with which the indexed document has a relationship.

So, let's say I have two Kinds:

```
class Store(BaseHandler):
    store_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    logo_url = ndb.StringProperty()
    about_store = ndb.TextProperty()

class Product(BaseHandler):
    product_name = ndb.StringProperty
    store_key = ndb.KeyProperty() #Store entity which created this product.
```

Then, I add each new Product entity to the index, like this:

```
class NewProduct(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, store_id):
        self.render('new-product.html')


    def post(self, store_id):
        product_name = self.request.get('product_name')
        store_key = ndb.Key('Store', store_id)

        try:
            p = Product(
                store_key = store_key,
                product_name = product_name)

            p.put()

            # Add p to index
            p_doc = search.Document(
                doc_id = str(p.key.id()),
                fields = [
                    search.AtomField(name = 'store_id', value = str(str_id)),
                    search.TextField(name = 'product_name', value = e.product_name)])
            index = search.Index('product_index')
            index.put(p_doc)
        except:
            # handle error
```

Now, if I run a search query using...

```
index = search.Index('product_index')
index.search('PRODUCT_NAME')
```

I should be able to return all the `Product` documents from the index by its query string.

My question is: How do I *efficiently* return a result object which contains **both** the product document AND its `Store` kind information (store_name, logo_url, about_store)?

Comment: you're just going to have to put all of the store fields into the search document.  Note that you can also put many fields of the same name into the same document... so you could create a document with all of your store information and also put all of your product information into it... and search it quite easily